# A lower bound on the form of the resolvent operator

Tags: matrices, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n,n}$ and $x\in\mathbb{C}^{n}$, $\|x\|=1$. Is there any $c(z)>0$ such that 
$$|\langle x, (A-z)^{-1} x \rangle|\geq c(z), \quad \text{ for } |z|>\|A\|\,?$$
Recall that it is well known that 
$$ \|(A-z)^{-1}\|\geq\frac{1}{\operatorname{dist}(z,\sigma(A))}.$$

Comment: For $|z| > 2 \|A\|$ one can get a coarse estimate $c(z) = {1 \over |z|} (1- { \|A\| \over |z|-\|A\|} )$.

Comment: to copper.hat : Can you explain how to derive this bound or give a reference? Thanks!

Comment: I'll write it up when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, just an elaboration of a comment.

You have
$(A-zI)^{-1} = (z({A \over z} -I))^{-1} = {1 \over z} ({A \over z} -I)^{-1} = -{1 \over z} (I-{A \over z} )^{-1}$. If $|z| > \|A\|$, we have
$(A-zI)^{-1} = -{ 1\over z} (\sum_{k=0}^\infty ({A \over z})^k) = -{ 1\over z} (I+{A \over z}\sum_{k=0}^\infty ({A \over z})^k)$.

Note that $\|{A \over z}\sum_{k=0}^\infty ({A \over z})^k)\| \le { \|{A \over z}\| \over 1-\|{A \over z}\|}$.

Then
$\langle x, (A-zI)^{-1} x \rangle = -{1 \over z}(1+\langle x, {A \over z}\sum_{k=0}^\infty ({A \over z})^k x \rangle )$ and so
$|\langle x, (A-zI)^{-1} x \rangle| = {1 \over |z|} |1+\langle x, {A \over z}\sum_{k=0}^\infty ({A \over z})^k x \rangle ) | \ge {1 \over |z|}(1-{ \|{A \over z}\| \over 1-\|{A \over z}\|})$.

If we let $c(z) = {1 \over |z|}(1-{ \|{A \over z}\| \over 1-\|{A \over z}\|})$,
we see that if $|z| > 2 \|A\|$, then $c(z) >0$.